# pip freeze and order of dependencies

Tags: python, pip

```
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`
```

automatically writes my dependencies in an apparently alphabetically order, like this:-

```
matplotlib==1.2.0
numpy==1.6.2
pandas==0.9.1
```

The problem with this is that `pip install -r requirements.txt` (when I deploy my code with its dependencies listed in `requirements.txt`) will end up failing because matplotlib needs numpy to be installed first.

How can I ensure that matplotlib is listed **after** numpy in the `requirements.txt` file when I `pip freeze` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case it does not matter, because `pip` builds every requirements (calling `python setup.py egg_info` for each) and then install them all. For your specific case, it does not matter, because `numpy` is currently required to be installed while building `matplotlib`.

It is a problem with `matplotlib`, and they created a proposal to fix it: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/MEP11

See comments from this issue at pip issue tracker: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/25

This question is a duplicate of [Matplotlib requirements with pip install in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797688/matplotlib-requirements-with-pip-install-in-virtualenv).

Answer (score 2):

A file containing the packages in the desired order can be used like so:

```
pip freeze -r sorted-package-list.txt > requirements.txt
```

Where `sorted-package-list.txt` contains

```
numpy
matplotlib
```

Note: Packages not included in the `sorted-package-list.txt` file are appended at the end of the requirements file.

Example result:

```
numpy==1.14.1
matplotlib==2.2.3
## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:
pandas==0.23.4
```

Comment: Check out `pip freeze --help` for more options.

Answer (score 1):

You can try command

`pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt`

This installs the packages without dependencies and possibly you will get rid above written problems.

Comment: You mean `--no-deps`. But that could potentially cause problems with other packages that do have dependencies and need those dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that h5py (the HDF5 Python wrapper) has the same problem.

My workaround is to split the output of `pip freeze` into two: into a short requirements file containing only numpy's version `${NUMPY_REQS}`, and a long one `${REQS}` containing all other packages. Note the `-v` switch of the second `grep`, the "inverse match".

```
pip freeze | tee >( grep  '^numpy' > ${NUMPY_REQS} ) | grep -v '^numpy' > ${REQS}
```

And then invoke `pip install` *twice* (e.g. when installing a virtual env):

```
# this installs numpy
pip install -r ${NUMPY_REQS}

# this installs everything else, h5py and/or matplotlib are happy
pip install -r ${REQS}
```

Note that this `tee` / `grep` magic combo works on Unix-like systems only. No idea how to achieve the same thing on Windows.