# pip dependency resolution fails when install both numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip

Starting from a clean python 2.7.3 installation, if I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

with the following requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Cache==0.12
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.4
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.23
wsgiref==0.1.2
numpy==1.7.1
PIL==1.1.7
matplotlib==1.2.1
```

then pip attempts to install matplotlib before numpy and fails with:

```
============================================================================
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: 1.2.1
                python: 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)  [GCC 4.7.2]
              platform: linux2

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: no
                        * You must install numpy 1.4 or later to build
                        * matplotlib.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
============================================================================
```

However, if I do

```
pip install numpy
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then everything works fine. What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib requirements with pip install in virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797688/matplotlib-requirements-with-pip-install-in-virtualenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip doesn't naively differentiate between 'runtime' and 'compiletime' requirements.  Both `numpy` and `matplotlib` have significant c/c++ extensions which need to be done in the right order.

There was a recent PR [#2445](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2445) related to this which will (I think) make it into 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

PIP installs in alphabetical order, so in your requirements script it tries to install matplotlib before numpy. Since matplotlib is dependent on numpy it gives the error you received. Doing `pip install numpy` before  `pip install -r requirements.txt` installs numpy before it goes through the requirements.txt, so this time when it gets to matplotlib, numpy is already installed.

See also: [pip freeze and order of dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892250/pip-freeze-and-order-of-dependencies)