# Installing Requirements for Heroku Server

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pip

I am currently trying to set up a Flask webserver on Heroku, following the following instructions: http://virantha.com/2013/11/14/starting-a-simple-flask-app-with-heroku/

Right now I am trying to install requirements on a virtualenv so that I can deploy the app locally. However, when I run 'pip install -r requirements.txt', I get the following error log (including just the tail):

```
Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting imread==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
Using cached imread-0.5.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File    "/private/var/folders/c3/nwlcwspn7l16n19lhzd7xky00000gn/T/pip-build-X2ZNNp/imread/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/c3/nwlcwspn7l16n19lhzd7xky00000gn/T/pip-build-X2ZNNp/imread/
```

I tried fixing the errors by following the instructions at this thread: [Can't install via pip because of egg_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error) 
but to no avail.

I'm wondering if anyone has any insights to offer for other things I can try, as I've been stuck on this for a few hours now.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `requirements.txt` have `numpy` as a requirement? As it appears that `imread` requires the dependency but may not go through the proper steps to install it.

Comment: Yup. Numpy was already there, and I even moved the install for the requirement (numpy==1.11.0) to the top of the requirements.txt file. Still getting the same error. :(

Comment: It appears that the order of the `requirements.txt` doesn't matter based off this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4996589/6061947). So if possible I would suggest running `pip install numpy` prior, or install using the operating systems package manager.